# Redirección net.tcp con nginx

Tags: servidor, nginx, proxy

Estoy montando un reverse proxy en el cuál se accederá desde diferentes subdominios, mediante https y serán redireccionados a un servicio WCF.

Ejemplos de acceso:

- https://sub1.dominio.com
- https://sub2.dominio.com

Por lo tanto:

- cuando acceda sub1, deberá ir a la IP 192.168.1.1:1000
- cuando acceda sub2 deberá ir a la IP 192.168.1.1:2000

En las cuáles habrá un servicio escuchando.

Actualmente tengo configurado tanto el que todas las peticiones pasen a https, como que me haga un reverse proxy para ver una web montada en un servidor (esto ha sido parte de las pruebas de configuración)

**Redirección a https**

```
server {
        listen 80;
        listen [::]:80;

        server_name *.dominio.com;

        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}
```

Ahora la duda nos surge para como montar la redirección tanto con http con puerto, como por net.tcp.

**Prueba de redirección**
    server {
            # SSL Configuracion
            listen   443;

```
        ssl    on;
        ssl_certificate    /etc/ssl/star_xxx_com.pem;
        ssl_certificate_key    /etc/ssl/star_xxx_com.key;

        server_name sub.domain.com;

        access_log /var/log/nginx/nginx.vhost.access.log;
        error_log /var/log/nginx/nginx.vhost.error.log;

        location / {
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host:$server_port;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Server $host;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                rewrite ^ http://192.168.1.1:8732/ruta/redireccion/ permanent;
        }
}
```

Como véis estoy intentando hacer que la petición externa que llega a nuestro router sea por https, una vez la recibimos la enrutamos según el subdominio al servicio WCF correspondiente.

La idea es poder llamar a dichos servicios por una url segura y no por IP

Por lo tanto, aclarando un poco sobre la duda.

- ¿Se puede hacer una redirección hacia un puerto net.tcp con NGINX?
- ¿Es correcta la forma en la que estoy procediendo a realizar el proxy
  inverso, con el rewrite, o es mejor usar proxy_pass?

Comment: Hola has encontrado alguna solución? Creo que como proxy inverso puedes hacer algo pero no he podido con nginx y net.tcp

Comment: Hola, nada lo di por imposible, por mas que miré no conseguí avanzar nada.